# Speech-to-text recognition of multiple voices with Microsoft Speech API?

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, voice-recognition, azure-speech

I would like to know if **Microsoft Speech API on Python supports multiple voices recognition.** I saw the beta of SDK Speaker Recognition, but I was wondering if this feature was already in the Speech SDK or not.

I have checked all the python SDK methods documentation and searched over the web and stackoverflow if anyone ever needed/tried multiple voice recognition in speech-to-text using MS Speec, but I couldn't find anything about it.

When I transcribed an audio of a two persons conversation (a female and a male) using Microsoft Speech-to-Text, the recognized text was not split when the voice changes.